# Slider on my asp page is not working!! just two text boxes

Tags: asp.net, slider, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to implement a very simple slider using ajax control toolbox.
I saw many examples online like these

http://aj-learning.com/blog/ajax-sliderextender-asp-net/

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/43508-How-create-Slider-ASP-NET-using-AJAX.aspx

and tried

```
       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender ID="SliderExtender1" runat="server" 
Minimum="-100" Maximum="100" BoundControlID="TextBox8" TargetControlID="TextBox9">

    </ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender>
        <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager2" runat="server">
        </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

However,

After running the program, I cannot see the slider
What I see is only two text boxes!!!

What is wrong with this?